Bibliometric & Co-occurrence Analysis
I am very new to network analysis and bibliometrics. So excuse for my silly & basic question.
I am interested to find how Journals (academic) are related to one another. Each journals have their own aims and scope. From these aims and scope, I have keywords. Using these keywords, I want to identify which journals are connected (bibliometrics/ network analysis). I will explain with an example below.



Journal
Keywords




A
salt; chicken; pepper; powder; sauce.


B
cats; mouse; cage; litter


C
chicken; burger; sauce; bread


D
dogs; cats; cows; pets; animals; birds


E
chicken; curry; sauce


F
burger; flour; sugar; sesame; salt


G
chicken; rice; pepper; salt



From the simple example below, we know that Journals A, E, G can be related because of co occurring keywords. I have more than 200 journals to analyse. So I want to do network analysis. Note that not all journals have equal number of keywords.
Hope to get some feed back.
Cheers.
So far, I tried using VOS viewer, but was not successful.
